# Variable outside a try catch block loses value

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a little problem. I have a function with a string outside a try-catch-finally block that is changed depending on what happens inside the block. Once that is finished, I want to display it. My problem is that the value that was changed in the block returns to the original value it had. How can I fix this?

```
string error = "No issues";

try{
    error = "Correct";
}catch(Exception ex){
    error = "Wrong:" + ex.Message.ToString();
}finally{
    // Closes connection
}

MessageBox.Show(error);
```

Comment: No sample code?  Really?

Comment: Change it in `finally`. It will always run (modulo bomb explosion, JVM bug, blackout).

Comment: it would help for you to show your current code

Comment: An exception is no doubt being thrown before your assignment takes place. Need to see your code though..

Comment: @lukas: No JVM bug will impact .NET code :-)

Comment: Well, that's the issue, no exception is being thrown. It just exits normally. It loses its value when it reaches the end.

Comment: There is no problem with that code.  Please provide a code sample that we can execute that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will show a message box with the text

> Correct

if no exceptions are thrown, otherwise the message

> Wrong: (plus the exception's message property)

It will never show the message

> No issues

because you overwrite the initial value of `error` in the first line of your try block.

`error` will never *lose* a value (as in I guess become *null*) given the code you post.  Eventually *error* will go out of scope (e.g. when you exit the method that this code is defined in).

**UPDATE**

I took your code, created a brand-new WinForms project, double-clicked on Form1 to create a Load event handler, and posted in your code like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string error = "No issues";

        try
        {
            error = "Correct";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = "Wrong:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closes connection
        }

        MessageBox.Show(error);
    }
```

The result was a message box that said "Correct".

If that is not what you see in your real code, you are not sharing enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, that's just the thing: It shows me "No issues", when it shouldn't. I tracked it through the whole thing, but as soon as it exits it goes back to the initial value "No issues".

Comment: @JesusZamora As soon as it exits it has no value at all.

Comment: No, it does have a value. It comes in with it and once the try catch clock ends it goes back to the value which with it was initialized. It never turns to null.

Comment: @JesusZamora: I can only imagine you're not posting enough code to fully reproduce what you are seeing.  See my update.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, if the string in question declared outside the method. If you are 100% sure, that a new value is given to the string, the following code will probably do the problem you have:

```
static void Foo(string s)
{
    try
    {
        s = "OK";
    }
    catch { }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string temp = "??";
    Foo(temp);
    Console.WriteLine(temp); //prints ??
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

as you are passing string by value. If you need to change the value you should either:

make a `ref` parameter:

```
static void Foo(ref string s)
```

and call it

```
Foo(ref temp);
```

or return the new value from the method:

```
    static string Foo(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            s = "OK";
        }
        catch { }
        return s;
    }
```

and call it:

```
temp = Foo(temp);
```